# How to plot percentiles of Poisson distribution in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability, poisson

How can i obtain and plot the percentiles of a Poisson distribution in R ? Basically i want to create a plot that shows year ( ie yr) in x-axis, 50th percentile (median) of Poisson distribution as a line in y-axis. My sample data and script are below.

```
dt<-structure(list(yr = 1979:2008, cn = c(9, 15, 17, 11, 9, 10, 8, 
 10, 18, 12, 11, 14, 12, 16, 10, 13, 9, 9, 11, 11, 14, 14, 10, 
 11, 14, 15, 14, 12, 9, 12), `inn` = c(1.12666666666667, 1.35666666666667, 
 -0.0533333333333333, -0.166666666666667, 0.213333333333333, -0.0533333333333333, 
 -1.32, 0.0633333333333333, -0.22, 0.01, -0.456666666666667, -1.01, 
 -0.326666666666667, 0.0233333333333334, -0.496666666666667, -1.24, 
 0.2, -0.46, 0.32, 0.63, 0.466666666666667, -0.0233333333333333, 
 0.33, 0.503333333333333, 0.0566666666666667, -0.396666666666667, 
 0.58, -0.596666666666667, 0.98, 1.01666666666667)), .Names = c("yr", 
 "cn", "inn"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("grouped_df", 
 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "yr", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
 yr = 1979:2008), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame", vars = "yr", drop = TRUE, .Names = "yr"))

model=glm(dt$cn~dt$inn, family=poisson(link=log))
summary(model)
model$fitted

## create the plot
P<-ggplot(dt, aes(x = yr)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = cn))
P
```

Comment: How do you want to plot them? also like dots of a different color... a line connecting those means?

Comment: The glm function does not estimate the median. You may need to use quantile regression. It's also unclear what you intend to do with the model since your plot only has the "Y values" and not the independent variables that go into the model. Is the intent to use a prediction at the median of the "X values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the following is your desired code

```
# prepare a single dataframe containing all the information
dataPlot = data.frame(x = dt$yr # x values
                      , y = dt$cn # y points
                      , q875 = qpois(0.875, model$fitted) # upper bound of 75% confidence interval
                      , q625 = qpois(0.625, model$fitted) # upper bound of 25% confidence interval
                      , q50 = qpois(0.50, model$fitted) # median
                      , q375 = qpois(0.375, model$fitted) # lower bound of 25% confidence interval
                      , q125 = qpois(0.125, model$fitted) # lower bound of 75% confidence interval
           );

# create the plot object
P <- ggplot(dataPlot, aes(x = x), ) + # add data and set x-axis
            geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q125, ymax=q875), fill = "gray") +  # color the area of 75% confidence interval (the area is colored between `ymin` and`ymax` - see ?geom_ribbon
            geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q375, ymax=q625), fill = "lightgray") +  # color the area of 25 confidence interval 
            geom_point(aes(y = y)) + # add the points
            geom_line(aes(y = q50)) # add median lines
# and plot it
P
```

---

With your data the bandwidth are two straight rectangular, the following normal random data will let you see a plot which is more similar to your picture plot

```
m = rexp(NROW(dt), rate=2) # generate random means
s = rexp(NROW(dt), rate=5) # generate random standard deviations
dataPlot = data.frame(x = dt$yr # your x-values
                    , y = rnorm(NROW(dt), mean=m, sd=s) # random y-values
                    , q875 = qnorm(0.875, mean=m, sd=s) # from now on, see previous comments
                    , q625 = qnorm(0.625, mean=m, sd=s)
                    , q50 = qnorm(0.50, mean=m, sd=s)
                    , q375 = qnorm(0.375, mean=m, sd=s)
                    , q125 = qnorm(0.125, mean=m, sd=s)
            )
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what i was looking for :)